# Слова "жалко" и "жалить"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Являются ли однокоренными слова "жалко" и "жалить" и, если да, как такое могло получиться?

Answer (score 3):

Слова не родственны по крайней мере на уровне русского языка.
"Жалко" - от жалеть, жалить - от жало.
Первый корень, писался через е, другая ступень чередования а/е возможно в "желати" - любить.
Второй - через Я (йотованный ЮС малый).

Вместе с тем просматривается определённая связь на уровне индоевропейской общности - с общим значением, болеть, переживать, жалить.
См. Фасмера.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу откомментировать, поэтому напишу так.

> Слова не родственны по крайней мере

Есть два слова "жалко": наречие "жалко" и существительное "жалко" (уменьшительное от "жало"). В зависимости от того, что имел в виду автор вопроса, ответ будет немного разный.

Answer (score 0):

Слова — однокоренные. Одно из значений слова "жалить" — ранить, впиваясь жалом. Что Вас удивляет?

Comment: Прошу прощения, это было "жалко", а не "жало" - просто, опечатка.